# How to consolidate all custom processes in ADO to create standards

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have only one organization in my ADO and there is a limit of 128 custom processes that can be created. I am at my limit and would like to consolidate some custom processes to make space for future process.

I wonder if there is a way to query and compare all the custom processes to determine which similarity and differences to deprecate the one that repeated.

Any idea on how to create standard on custom processes to avoid team to create unnecessary custom processes when it already exists?

Adding another organization in ADO is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is a way to query and compare all the custom processes to determine which similarity and differences to deprecate the one that repeated.

If you are using Hosted XML process, you can [export the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/import-process?view=azure-devops) and compare the XML. If you are using inherited processes, there isn't such feature can query and compare the different processes.

> Any idea on how to create standard on custom processes to avoid team to create unnecessary custom processes when it already exists?

To create, edit, and manage processes, you must be a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group, or have the corresponding collection-level permissions **Create process**, **Delete process**, **Edit process**, or **Delete a field from organization** set to Allow.
[image]

To avoid team to create unnecessary custom processes, it is recommended that you only give specific users permission to manage processes. If other users need customized work items or fields, they can apply to the administrator, who can make changes to the original process or create a new process. When creating a new process, you can add a description to distinguish it.